# include no.of associations in to_JSON rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have a relation in rails models like this , subject has many units and units have many questions. 
So in controller returning response like this

```
    @response = subject.as_json()
@response["units"] = subject.units.to_json()
```

now in this i want to include the count of number of questions available in those each units of that subject.

doing this

```
    @response["units"] = subject.units.to_json(:include => :questions)
```

will give include a array of all the questions in that unit.. but i need only the count to be sent.

I can actually write a method in units controller to return questions count but that is not very feasible for me. 
So, let me know if it is possible to include count directly through :include.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're going to run a count on the questions table every time you do this.

You should look into the `counter_cache` feature in Rails. Since you're going to want this value every time you get this response it makes sense to cache the count on the parent `unit` rather than run a count every time.

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options

Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Just by the by, you'll get more and better answers if you increase your accept rate. It's very low at 29%.

Comment: that would help me for sure. but i have this association relation in different levels. So i should end up adding five to six new tables for that..

Comment: You should read the docs, you don't have to add any new tables to get `counter_cache` to work.

Comment: ooh sorry.. my bad.. i misunderstood the concept.. this would work me thanks.. i just need to add a new column..